# Derivative of $f(z)=z^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to take the branch cut as the positive real axis and then take the derivative of this function using polar form. In particular I got to $$f(z)=z^{1/2}=(re^{i\theta})^{1/2}=r^{1/2}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$$
But I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help?

Comment: Use the chain rule or product rule on the statement that $(f(z))^2 = z$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $f$ is differentiable at $z_0=r_0e^{i\theta_0}$ then the derivative 
$$f'(z_0)= \lim_{re^{i\theta}\to r_0e^{i\theta_0}} \frac{f(re^{i\theta})-f(r_0e^{i\theta_0})}{re^{i\theta}-r_0e^{i\theta_0}}$$ is *independent* of how $z=re^{i\theta}\to z_0$.
Hence, to calculate the limit, you can choose a simple way to approach $z_0$. 
In particular, $z_0$ lies on the line $\theta=\theta_0$ (i.e. line passing 
through origin and making angle $\theta_0$ with
positive real axis) so we can let $z$ approaches $z_0$ along this line. In other words, $z=re^{i\theta_0}$ and $z\to z_0$ when $r\to r_0$. This means
$$f'(z_0)=\lim_{r\to r_0} \frac{f(re^{i\theta_0})-f(r_0e^{i\theta_0})}{(r-r_0)
e^{i\theta_0}}=e^{-i\theta_0} \lim_{r\to r_0}\frac{f(re^{i\theta_0})-f(r_0e^{i\theta_0})}{(r-r_0)}.$$
The limit should be easier to calculate now.